# Entity Framework - Multiple Foreign Keys Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a `Project` model which has a `ProjectLead` (one instance of the `Person` Foreign Key), this works fine. But now I also need to add a collection of `People` (Project members) referencing the same `Person` table and I can't get the Entity Framework to generate my database. As soon as I try to add the Fluent API code to create the link table `ProjectPerson` I get an error - "Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The relationship 'MyApp.WebApi.Models.Person_Projects' was not loaded because the type 'MyApp.WebApi.Models.Person' is not available."  I assume this is because of the existing FK relationship already in place with `ProjectLead`.

**Project Model:**

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Foreign Key - Project lead (Person)
    public int ProjectLeadId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person ProjectLead { get; set; }

    // Create many to many relationship with People - Team members on this project
    public ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }

    public Project()
    {
        People = new HashSet<Person>();
    }
}
```

**Person Model:**

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public String Firstname { get; set; }
    public String Surname { get; set; }

    // Create many to many relationship
    public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        Projects = new HashSet<Project>();
    }
}
```

**DB Context:**

```
public class HerculesWebApiContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // This works fine
        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
                    .HasRequired(c => c.ProjectLead)
                    .WithMany(d => d.Projects)
                    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ProjectLeadId)
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        // Adding these lines to create the link table `PersonProjects` causes an error

        //modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasMany(t => t.Projects).WithMany(t => t.People);

        //modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasMany(t => t.People).WithMany(t => t.Projects);
    }
}
```

I gather that perhaps I need to use the `InverseProperty` attribute, but I am not sure where this should go in this case?

Comment: It might help if you said exactly what errors you are getting.  "causes an error" is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks, added error msg to post.

Comment: Why are you even adding fluent configuration?  Your configuration just does the same thing the normal conventions do.  Secondly, you probably want to make your collections virtual since you probably don't want to be including every related person every time you query a project.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - Thanks, yes I will make the collections virtual. I am using the fluent API because I have a non-standard Foreign Key ID `ProjectLeadId`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you explicitly define your join table?  So, define a ProjectPeople relationship and make the code something like this...

```
 public class ProjectPerson{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectPersonId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Project")]
    public int? ProjectId {get;set;}
    public virtual Project {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int? PersonId {get;set;}
    public virtual Person {get;set;}

    public string RelationshipType {get;set;}
 }
```

Then your other 2 classes will look like this...

```
public class Project
{
   [Key]
   public int ProjectId { get; set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }

   // Foreign Key - Project lead (Person)
   public int ProjectLeadId { get; set; }
   public virtual Person ProjectLead { get; set; }

   // Create many to many relationship with People - Team members on this project
   public virtual ICollection<ProjectPerson> ProjectPeople { get; set; }

   public Project()
   {
       ProjectPerson = new HashSet<ProjectPerson>();
   }
```

}

And this..

```
Public class Person
{
  [Key]
  public int PersonId { get; set; }

  public String Firstname { get; set; }
  public String Surname { get; set; }

  // Create many to many relationship
  public virtual ICollection<ProjectPerson> ProjectPeople { get; set; }


  public Person()
  {
     ProjectPerson = new HashSet<ProjectPerson>();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea. How would I then avoid pulling back the entire table of `ProjectPeople` every time I `Get` a `project` with it's `People`? Would I do this in my controller, something like `return db.Projects.Include("ProjectPeople").Where(e => e.ProjectId == id).AsEnumerable();`

Comment: You could, but in this case you can use lazy loading and keep from preempting the relationship and remove the "Include".  Then, when you want to query your join relationship you could do tons of operations to filter out your results. (Also, just as a tip, I would put something like this in a View Model to keep your controller from explicitly defining the query.)